# Diffusion with a source

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In Partial Differential Equations by Walter Strauss, Ch 3.3 Diffusion with a Source, the author solves the inhomogeneous diffusion equation:

$u_t - k u_{xx} = f(x,t)$

$u(x,0)=\phi(x)$

They assume the solution has the following form, which they subsequently verify:

$u(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} S(x-y,t)\phi (y)dy+\int_0^t\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} S(x-y,t-s) f(y,s) dy ds$

I'm stuck at a particular step where they use the fact that:

$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} S(x-y,\epsilon)f(y,t)dy=f(x,t)$

(at least I believe this is what they are using).

They mention that they use the initial condition satisfied by S.

Why does the equality above hold?

Comment: If you were to "plug in" $t=0$ on both sides you would get that $$u(x,0) = \phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty S(x-y,0)\phi(y)\:dy + 0$$ where the equality of the middle two terms is what you are after. The proper way to interpret the equality is with a one sided limit $t\to0^+$

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now. I think I got it in my head that I was looking for something involving $f(x,t)$ and not $\phi(x)$, so I must have inadvertently missed this.